# Переопределение встроенного print

Tags: python, консоль, логирование, print, ansi

Подскажите, реально переопределить встроенный print таким образом, чтобы он принимал произвольный ключевой аргумент?

```
print("test.", color=Fore.GREEN)
```

Хочу таким образом реализовать вывод цветного текста в терминал и параллельное логирование всего, но уже без ANSI escape characters.

```
class Logger(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.terminal = sys.stdout
            now = datetime.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y-%I_%M_%S_%p')
            self.log = open("log_for_" + now + ".log", "a", encoding="utf-8")

        def write(self, message, color=""):
            self.terminal.write(color + message)
            self.log.write(message)  

        def flush(self):
            pass
```

Либо как решить подобную задачу хорошо?

Comment: Это возможно, но не "хорошо", в принципе переопределять стандартные функции не хорошо) Переопределять фактически придется во всех ваших модулях, например вынести определение вашего print в отдельный модуль, и везде его импортировать.

Comment: Еще, желательно как-то разделить выделение цветом в консоли и логирование  (по принципу единственной ответственности)

Comment: @insolor можно монкипатчнуть билтингс) но обычно в проекте конечное количество модулей и в каждом можно сделать from myutils import print

Comment: А ещё можно патчнуть sys.stdout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы конечно можете переопределить функцию `print`, но я бы советовал подумать о другом подходе, это достаточно плохая практика.

Если все таки решите переопределять, то пример ниже, функцию объявляем вне класса

```py
from builtins import print as base_print

def print(*args, **kwargs):
  if kwargs.get("color"):
    # Ваша логика
    # ...
    # Следующие три строки это пример логики:
    color = kwargs.pop("color") # не забываем удалить значение из kwargs
    base_print(color, sep="")
    base_print(*args, **kwargs)
  else:
    base_print(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
print("hello", [1,2,3,4], color="green")

вывод:
green
hello [1,2,3,4]
```

```
print("hello", [1,2,3,4])

вывод:
hello [1,2,3,4]
```

UPD: как заметил коментатор @Danis, если требуется оставить стандартный вывод при любой ситуацию, то можно упростить код

```py
from builtins import print as base_print

def print(*args, **kwargs):
  if kwargs.get("color"):
    # Ваша логика
    # ...
    # Следующие три строки это пример логики:
    color = kwargs.pop("color") # не забываем удалить значение из kwargs
    base_print(color, sep="")
  base_print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: можно убрать `else` и поставить один `base_print`

Comment: да, спасибо, действительно можно, но я точно не знаю необходимую логику спросившего, может ему не нужен будет стандартный вывод при дополнительном параметре и захочет это тоже кастомизировать